# Search field with output to /users/view/# if the entered user name exists. Is controller action necessary in CakePHP 3.5?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

On my front page I want to have a search field with the button "Find member". If the member with the entered name exists, pressing the button should redirect to `/users/view/N`, where N is a user `id`. if not - flash message `Could not find user with username %s', $username.` I have a table users with `id` and `username`.

I tried this:

```
$this->Html->link((h($user->username)), ['controller' => 'Users','action' => 'view', $user->id])
```

and this

```
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')
        $username = trim($this->request->getData('User.username')); 
$user = $this->Users->find()->where(['Users.username LIKE ',  $username . '%'])->select(['Users.id', 'Users.username'])->first()); 
if ($user instanceof \Cake\ORM\Entity) { return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', 'id' => $user->username]); } 
else { $this->Flash->warning(sprintf('Could not find user with username %s', $username)); } 

  $this->set(compact('user'));
$this->Form->create($user)
```

all in template, without using controller. Nothing worked. If controller is necessary, what should go there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div class="search">
    <?= $this->Form->create(null) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button('Search') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

then in the corresponding controller

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
         $username = $this->request->getData('username'); 

         $user = $this->Users->find()->where(['username' => $username])->first();
          if ($user) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user is found.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $user->id]);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('This user does not exist.'));

         }
```

thanks to the guys from CakePHP forum.